# Dojo ToggleButton Check Icon doesn't update

Tags: javascript, dojo, togglebutton, checked

I am defining a toggle button in HTML and then updating it's checked state in JavaScript based on another toggle button.

Toggle Button:
 `<input type="checkbox" dojoType="dijit.form.ToggleButton" iconClass="dijitCheckBoxIcon" label="Assigned Work" id="AssignedWork" >`

When the app runs I want this toggle button to be un-checked.

I can successfully call the checked property like this:

`Registry.byId("AssignedWork").checked = true;`

However my toggle button's icon isn't updating to indicate the "Check". When my mouse cursor hovers over the toggle button the button refreshes and shows the check mark. Is there a way to get the check icon to turn on with the .checked property?

Comment: I found that I can do this to set the icon:     `    Registry.byId("AssignedWork").set("iconClass", "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconPaste");`  I am still trying to figure out what the name of the "checked" icon is and how to set that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use set like

```
Registry.byId("AssignedWork").set("checked",true);
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t47DR/2/

You should also be aware that the syntax you are using is very outdated, so if you aren't using an older version of dojo, change your syntax.

Comment: Matt, I am pretty new to dojo/JavaScript etc. I am using samples from https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/ to build applications with a map.  Do you have a suggestion for a dojo resource to learn the newer syntax? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @bives, checkout http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/ you'll see that for defining dojo objects declaratively you should use "data-dojo-type" instead of "dojoType" and more.